# Flot-bar-chart not rendering in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache, httpd.conf

After the following Apache server security update on my application server, a flot-bar-chart is not rendering in PHP, although two pie-charts are. The bar chart works correctly on my local Apache web server.

"It was discovered that the HTTP parser in httpd incorrectly allowed certain characters not permitted by the HTTP protocol specification to appear unencoded in HTTP request headers. If httpd was used in conjunction with a proxy or backend server that interpreted those characters differently, a remote attacker could possibly use this flaw to inject data into HTTP responses, resulting in proxy cache poisoning."

I get the following error: Syntax Error: expected expression, got ',' index.php: 412:16

Here is the JS code for both types of charts, embedded in home.view (HTML):

```
<script language='javascript'>
function plot_bar(data) {
    options = {
        legend:{position:"nw"},
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "week: %x, Number of consents: %y"
        },
        };
    $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"),data,options);
}

function plot_pie(data,id)
{
    $.plot($('#'+id), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages
            shifts: {
                x: 20,
                y: 0
            },
            defaultTheme: false
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The output for index.php: 412:16 looks like this:

```
<script language='javascript'>plot_pie([{label:'Empty',data:380},
{label:'Full',data:180}],'flot-pie1-chart')</script><script 
language='javascript'>plot_pie([{label:'Empty',data:560}],'flot-pie2-chart')
</script><script language='javascript'>plot_bar([{data:, label:'', lines:
{show:true},points:{show:true}},{data:[[45,52],[46,52],[47,27],[48,49],
[49,61],[50,43],[51,20],[52,20]], label:'2015', lines:{show:true},points:
{show:true}},{data:[[0,2],[1,23],[2,33],[3,32],[4,29],[5,44],[6,12],[7,17],
[8,22],[9,36],[10,23],[11,22],[12,23],[13,1],[14,58],[15,13],[16,31],
[17,20],[18,31],[19,40],[20,21],[21,19],[22,20],[23,19],[24,25],[25,21],
[26,44],[27,18],[28,18],[29,67],[30,126],[31,83],[32,103],[33,93],[34,82],
[35,124],[36,87],[37,83],[38,86],[39,69],[40,106],[41,107],[42,40],[43,73],
[44,110],[45,93],[46,57],[47,47],[48,54],[49,88],[50,111],[51,47],[52,36]], 
label:'2016', lines:{show:true},points:{show:true}},{data:[[1,101],[2,85],
[3,65],[4,110],[5,86],[6,82],[7,12],[8,91],[9,96],[10,37],[11,95],[12,92],
[13,38],[14,41],[15,63],[16,83],[17,72],[18,56],[19,77],[20,54],[21,46],
[22,47],[23,50],[24,71],[25,46],[27,1],[31,243],[32,113],[33,85],[34,79],
[35,51],[36,86],[37,86],[38,113],[39,112],[40,99],[41,109],[42,107],[43,89],
[44,123],[45,132],[46,92]], label:'2017', lines:{show:true},points:
{show:true}}])</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zu25mcbd/  One of your data is `data: ,`.  That's invalid json.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I traced back and found that the SQL query that populates the data was returning a null row with no year first, as the table I was pulling the year from had two null rows, due to an issue with the interface transactions that populate it. Once I deleted those null rows, the blanks for "data:, label:' ', lines: were eliminated.